# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode' error in django

Tags: django

I am trying to save the data in database using Python-Django. But i am getting this error:

```
'userInfo' object has no attribute 'suggestion'
```

This is my model.py file
model.py

```
class userInfo(models.Model):
        #user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        #age = models.IntegerField()
        u_name=models.TextField("Name",  null = True, blank = True)
        u_address=models.TextField("Address",  null = True, blank = True)
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.u_name
```

This is my view.py file
        view.py

```
    def gaurav(request):
        print request
        form=userInfoForm()
        if request.POST:
            form = userInfoForm(request.POST)
            anw=form.save(commit=False)
            anw.user=request.user
            anw.save()
            form= userInfoForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user1=form.save()
            return render(request, 'userview/home.html', {'form': form})
```

This is my form.py file
    form.py

```
    class userInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = userInfo
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
            super(userInfoForm,self).__init__()
```

Comment: I suggest not editing a question to be correct, instead mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 3):

Inside the`__unicode__` method of `userInfo`, you are trying to use `self.suggestion` but *suggestion* is not defined in the model fields.

Try using another attribute:

```
class userInfo(models.Model):
    # Model fields..
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.u_name
```

Comment: After this change, search `suggestion` in your code. Also, please paste the whole stacktrace of the error.

Comment: Thanks for helping, The problem is solved,,,,,,,i write super(userInfoForm,self).__init__() instead of super(userInfoForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the code as @Sunny Nanda Mentioned and still getting the same error, then try cleaning the .pyc files of that project and reload the dev server